# Gulp Export failing in Aurelia Skeleton ES Next after installing aurelia-autocomplete

Tags: gulp, aurelia, skeleton-code

I have been working for a while with Aurelia Skeleton ES next. Today I installed aurelia-autocomplete with:

```
jspm install aurelia-autocomplete
```

And I got this:

The following existing package versions were altered by install deduping:

```
   aurelia-pal 1.2.0 -> 1.3.0
   aurelia-dependency-injection 1.3.0 -> 1.3.1
   aurelia-logging 1.2.0 -> 1.3.1
   aurelia-framework 1.0.0 -> 1.1.2
   aurelia-templating 1.2.0 -> 1.4.1
   aurelia-fetch-client 1.0.0 -> 1.1.2
   aurelia-task-queue 1.1.0 -> 1.2.0
   aurelia-binding 1.1.1 -> 1.2.1
```

Now, 'gulp watch' is working correctly, BUT if I 'gulp export' the dependencies are not found anymore, and in the /dist folder the app is not working anymore.. what exactly happened here?

Comment: Did you adjust the `build/bundles.json` file with the plugin?

Comment: When you say "not working anymore", what's _actually not working_?

Comment: I should have been more precise,  the error I got is: "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///Users/mac/Desktop/aurelia%20js/skeleton-navigation-1.0.0/client/export/dist/aurelia.js
Line Number 1, Column 9:", which then triggers Unhandled rejection Error: (SystemJS).

And yes I have added  ""aurelia-autocomplete" entry in the /includes of bundles.js